# array of divs not being parsed in onclick function in javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to make a program where when the user clicks on any of the divs in the div of id `types, countries, languages, genres` that clicked div should be switching color to either green or black, and also list all the neighbor divs of that clicked div in the console. But for some reason it is only printing the divs of the last div of id `genres` in the console on any div clicked. Please Help

**My code's snippet:**

```js
var filter_options_div = document.getElementById("filter_options").children;
    for (var y = 0; y < filter_options_div.length; y++) {
        if (filter_options_div[y].tagName == "DIV") {
            var option = filter_options_div[y].querySelectorAll("div");
            for (var x = 0; x < option.length; x++) {
                option[x].style.backgroundColor = "green";
                var inserting = option;
                option[x].onclick = function() {
                    for (var z = 0; z < inserting.length; z++) {
                        console.log(inserting[z]);
                    }
                    if (this.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(51, 51, 51)") {
                        this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                    } else {
                        this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(51, 51, 51)";
                    }
                }; 
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
#filter_options {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: orange;
    float: left;
}

#filter_options p {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#filter_options div {
    background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#filter_options div div {
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px;
    background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="filter_options">
        <p></p>
        <div id="types">
            <div>Film</div><div>Tv-Show</div><div>Music</div>
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <div id="countries">
            <div>Australia</div><div>China</div><div>France</div><div>Hong-Kong</div><div>India</div><div>Japan</div><div>Canada</div><div>Germany</div><div>Italy</div><div>Spain</div><div>U.K.</div><div>United States</div>
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <div id="languages">
            <div>English</div><div>Hindi</div><div>Punjabi</div>
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <div id="genres">
            <div>Action</div><div>Adventure</div><div>Animation</div><div>Biography</div><div>Comedy</div><div>Crime</div><div>Documentary</div><div>Drama</div><div>Fantasy</div><div>Family</div><div>Foreign</div><div>History</div><div>Horror</div><div>Kids</div><div>Music</div><div>Magical realism</div><div>Mystery</div><div>News</div><div>Philosophical</div><div>Political</div><div>Reality</div><div>Romance</div><div>Saga</div><div>Satire</div><div>Sci-Fi</div><div>Social</div><div>Speculative</div><div>Sport</div><div>Talk</div><div>Thriller</div><div>Urban</div><div>Western</div><div>War</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'onclick' event handler function needs to be updated.

Also, given the 'inserting' variable scope with respect to 'onlick' function, it will have the same value for all handlers which is the last variable in the loop.

One way of solving this is updating the code as follows:

```
function getSiblings(el, filter) {
    var siblings = [];
    el = el.parentNode.firstChild;
    do { if (!filter || filter(el)) siblings.push(el); } while (el = el.nextSibling);
    return siblings;
}
var filter_options_div = document.getElementById("filter_options").children;
    for (var y = 0; y < filter_options_div.length; y++) {
        if (filter_options_div[y].tagName == "DIV") {
            var option = filter_options_div[y].querySelectorAll("div");
            for (var x = 0; x < option.length; x++) {
                option[x].style.backgroundColor = "green";
                var inserting = option;
                option[x].onclick = function(event) {
                    var neighbors = getSiblings(event.currentTarget);
                    for (var z = 0; z < neighbors.length; z++) {
                        console.log(neighbors[z]);
                    }
                    if (this.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(51, 51, 51)") {
                        this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                    } else {
                        this.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(51, 51, 51)";
                    }
                }; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: here is link to JsFiddle that contains the updated code to check too: https://jsfiddle.net/rsd93c0v/